# How to put my speech recognition app launcher icon at call dialler in Android

Tags: android, speech-recognition, phone-call, launcher, speech

I have developed a speech recognition android application. I wish to put it's launcher icon on call dialer so that user can launch it and app will record the call conversation for analysis.
How to do this?

Answer (score 0):

About placing an icon: The Launcher/Home app can only do this, and You can't tell it to do so, from your program.

About providing your app as alternative to dialer app: Make an activity that implies:

```
<intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.DIAL" />
</intent-filter>
```

in manifest file.

Comment: If I download any speech recognition android app on my android phone it asks for placing it to call dialer screen. I also wish to achieve this for my speech recognition app. How to do this?